# Creating tables in sqlite database on android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-logcat

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try{
                db.execSQL("create table " +          NotificationManager.getUserStatic(context) + "log ("+
                KEY_TIME +" INTEGER primary key, "+ KEY_TEXT +" TEXT not null);");

            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * onOpen method called when app is opening.
         */

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try{
                System.out.println("tophere");
                db.execSQL("create table if not exists "+DATABASE_NAME+"." + NotificationManager.getUserStatic(context) + "log ("+
                KEY_TIME +" INTEGER primary key, "+ KEY_TEXT +" TEXT not null);");
                System.out.println("downhere");
            }
            catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

We have this code for creating a database for an app. problem is, as far as we can tell, it doesn't create the tables, so when we try to insert into the tables and read from them, it crashes. we have tried everything, the System.out.println's are there to see where it fails. we get the tophere out, but it never gets to the downhere part in the log, so we are guessing something is causing it to fail there. we have checked with DDMS that the database is in the correct folder, so the database should be there, but for some reason it cant find it(line 2 and 3 in the log).

Any thoughts?

this is the error log:

```
04-27 10:45:46.768: I/System.out(6441): tophere
04-27 10:45:46.772: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6441): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = unknown database NOPO, db=/data/data/dmri.nopo/databases/NOPO
04-27 10:45:46.772: W/System.err(6441): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown database NOPO: , while compiling: create table if not exists NOPO.log (time INTEGER primary key, text TEXT not null);
04-27 10:45:46.792: W/System.err(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-27 10:45:46.792: W/System.err(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
04-27 10:45:46.811: W/System.err(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:134)
04-27 10:45:46.811: W/System.err(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
04-27 10:45:46.811: W/System.err(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
04-27 10:45:46.811: W/System.err(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:84)
04-27 10:45:46.811: W/System.err(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1899)
04-27 10:45:46.823: W/System.err(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1839)
04-27 10:45:46.823: W/System.err(6441):     at dmri.nopo.DBAdapter$DatabaseHelper.onOpen(DBAdapter.java:67)
04-27 10:45:46.823: W/System.err(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:180)
04-27 10:45:46.902: W/System.err(6441):     at dmri.nopo.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:86)
04-27 10:45:46.912: W/System.err(6441):     at dmri.nopo.LogManager.readLogFile(LogManager.java:32)
04-27 10:45:46.912: W/System.err(6441):     at dmri.nopo.LogActivity.onCreate(LogActivity.java:25)
04-27 10:45:46.921: W/System.err(6441):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-27 10:45:46.921: W/System.err(6441):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-27 10:45:46.931: W/System.err(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-27 10:45:46.931: W/System.err(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-27 10:45:46.941: W/System.err(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-27 10:45:46.941: W/System.err(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-27 10:45:46.953: W/System.err(6441):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 10:45:46.953: W/System.err(6441):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 10:45:46.972: W/System.err(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-27 10:45:46.972: W/System.err(6441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 10:45:46.972: W/System.err(6441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 10:45:46.982: W/System.err(6441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-27 10:45:46.982: W/System.err(6441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-27 10:45:46.992: W/System.err(6441):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 10:45:47.002: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6441): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: log, db=/data/data/dmri.nopo/databases/NOPO
04-27 10:45:47.012: D/AndroidRuntime(6441): Shutting down VM
04-27 10:45:47.012: W/dalvikvm(6441): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dmri.nopo/dmri.nopo.LogActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: log: , while compiling: SELECT time, text FROM log
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: log: , while compiling: SELECT time, text FROM log
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at dmri.nopo.DBAdapter.getAllSMS(DBAdapter.java:116)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at dmri.nopo.LogManager.readLogFile(LogManager.java:34)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at dmri.nopo.LogActivity.onCreate(LogActivity.java:25)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-27 10:45:47.181: E/AndroidRuntime(6441):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would recommend using android.util.Log for logging exceptions in Android.

Second - I suspect you have tables with wrong names created. Your error says query can't find "log", but I see you make some concatenation in "CREATE" statement. That may be the reason.

You can check what is actually created for you. By viewing the sqlite base created.

You can try:

1. `adb shell`
2. `cd /data/data/<your.package.name>/databases`
3. `sqlite3 <yourdbname>`
4. `.tables`

Comment: Is `adb shell` supposed to be run from within Android Studio, from its terminal?

Comment: @ColeTrumbo you can use any terminal, but you have to naviage to <sdk location>/platform-tools before executing adb commands

Answer (score 4):

this will help you i have tried it and its also working

this is just an example

```
public class DatabaseMarks {

    public static final String KEY_STUID = "stuid";
    public static final String KEY_SUB1 = "subject_one";
    public static final String KEY_SUB2 = "subject_two";
    public static final String KEY_SUB3= "subject_three";
    public static final String KEY_MARKS1= "marks_one";
    public static final String KEY_MARKS2 = "marks_two";
    public static final String KEY_MARKS3 = "marks_three";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student";
    private static final String DATABASE_MARKSTABLE = "StudentMarks";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_MARKSTABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_STUID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    KEY_SUB1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SUB2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SUB3 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_MARKS1 + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_MARKS2 + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_MARKS3 + " INTEGER NOT NULL);"
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_MARKSTABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
    public DatabaseMarks(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }
    public DatabaseMarks open()throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }
    public long createInsert(String stuid, String subject1, String subject2,
            String subject3, String marks1, String marks2, String marks3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_STUID, stuid);
        cv.put(KEY_SUB1, subject1);
        cv.put(KEY_SUB2, subject2);
        cv.put(KEY_SUB3, subject3);
        cv.put(KEY_MARKS1, marks1);
        cv.put(KEY_MARKS2, marks2);
        cv.put(KEY_MARKS3, marks3);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_MARKSTABLE, null, cv);

    }
```

Comment: it's helpful how i can test here if is an error i repeat means if the Primary is used ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `DATABASE_NAME` part of your SQLs.

If you want `NOPO` your database name, and want to create a table `log`, then:

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "NOPO", null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "log" + " ("
                + KEY_TIME +" INTEGER primary key, "
                + KEY_TEXT +" TEXT not null);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS log");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

`super(context, "NOPO", null, 2);` makes this DatabaseHelper object just in the `NOPO` database environment, so you need not to specify it in SQL.

ps. I hardcode something and you should AVOID it.

Comment: Why are we dealing with the onCreate and onOpen methods ? I am an iOS developer and I'm trying to "translate" (so to speak) my cocoa library so it could be used on Android. I need to create an SQLite database at runtime. I don't have an activity - since this is a library I'm creating. It seems I can't create a DB without an activity, is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";

```
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;

    // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
    // SQL Statement to create a new database.

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                 "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text,UNAME text); ";

    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;

    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() 
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
            public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
                private static String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
                private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

                String TABLE_NAME = "Student";

                String KEY_ID = "id";
                String KEY_STUDENT_NAME = "name";
                String KEY_STUDENT_MARKS = "marks";

            public DBHandler(Context context) {
                    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                }

        @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // creating table
                String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                        " ( " +
                        KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        KEY_STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT," +
                        KEY_STUDENT_MARKS + " INTEGER"
                        " ) ";
                db.execSQL(query);

            // insertion in the table
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_QUESTION_ID, "1");
            values.put(KEY_STUDENT_NAME , "abc");
            values.put(KEY_STUDENT_MARKS , "95");
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

            values.put(KEY_QUESTION_ID, "2");
            values.put(KEY_STUDENT_NAME , "def");
            values.put(KEY_STUDENT_MARKS , "93");
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            // Create tables again
            onCreate(db);
        }
     // retrieve date
     List<Student> getAllData(int Id) {

            List<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "    WHERE KEY_ID =" + "'" + Id + "'";

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Student std = new Student();
                    u.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    u.setStudentName(cursor.getString(1));
                    u.setMarks(cursor.getString(2));

                    student.add(std);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            // return student list
            return student;
        }
    }

     public class Student {

        public static int Id;
        public static String studentName;
        public static int marks;

        public int getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public static void setId(int id) {
            Id = id;
        }

        public String getStudentName() {
            return studentName;
        }

        public static void setStudentName(String studentName) {
            Student.studentName = studentName;
        }

        public int getMarks() {
            return marks;
        }

        public static void setMarks(int marks) {
            Student.marks = marks;
        }
    }

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            DBHandler db = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext());
            List<Student> std = new ArrayList<Student>();
            rl = db.getAllData(1);
           for (Student s : std) {
               Log.v("Id",s.getId());
               Log.v("Name",s.getStudentName());
               Log.v("Marks",s.getMarks());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: please elaborate your answer