# How to use double in Android via SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to work on some Android database/ sql stuff and have run into a snag. I am getting some errors and rather than pasting in an enormous chunk of code here, I thought I would narrow the question a bit. I was following the second response in this thread:

[Creating tables in sqlite database on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349337/creating-tables-in-sqlite-database-on-android)

And noticed that they used the "INTEGER" type for defining the column.

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_MARKSTABLE + " (" +
                KEY_STUID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                KEY_SUB1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SUB2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SUB3 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_MARKS1 + " **INTEGER** NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_MARKS2 + " **INTEGER** NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_MARKS3 + " **INTEGER** NOT NULL);"
        );
    }
```

My database will be using dollar amounts and percentages, meaning I will need decimal places. My question is, can you use the definition of DOUBLE here? Will it work? Is there a better option like FLOAT?

The only reason I don't just try this in code is that my pile of errors may mask the underlying issue and I might get a wrong answer.

Comment: There is no Double (or Float) in SQLite. Use REAL. http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: For monetary values, consider using fixed point integers instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a million for the help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using Real if you can.

These are the primitive types you can use when creating tables:

NULL. The value is a NULL value.

INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

More information [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: Welcome, please accept answer if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

use `REAL` datatype instead of `Double`.You can also use `Text` datatype for storing any kind of value.