# Table is not being created

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a database for my application.
My database cupboardTest.db is getting created, but the table is not being created.
I am not getting any error but the database is empty.
I tried to update my database_version also, but it doesn't help me.

Here is the DatabaseHelper:

```
public class KickStarterhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cupboardTest.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String TABLE_PROJECT = "project";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SERIAL_NO = "s_no";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMT_PLEDGED = "amt_pledged";
    public static final String COLUMN_BLURB = "blurb";
    public static final String COLUMN_BY =  "by";
    public static final String COLUMN_COUNTRY = "country";
    public static final String COLUMN_CURRENCY = "currency";
    public static final String COLUMN_END_TIME = "end_time";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String COLUMN_NUM_BACKERS = "num_backers";
    public static final String COLUMN_STATE = "state";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String COLUMN_URL = "url";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERCENTAGE = "percentage";

    public KickStarterhelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String CREATE_PROJECT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_PROJECT +"( " + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_AMT_PLEDGED + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_SERIAL_NO + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_BLURB + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_BY + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_COUNTRY + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_CURRENCY + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_END_TIME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_LOCATION + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NUM_BACKERS + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STATE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, "  +
                COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_URL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PERCENTAGE + " TEXT " + " )";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_PROJECT_TABLE);
        Log.e("table", "table created");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROJECT);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }

    public Boolean insertData(List<Kickstarter> mKickStarter){
        SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long result = 0l;
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < mKickStarter.size(); i++) {

            Log.e("vlaue inserting==", "" + mKickStarter.get(i));
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_SERIAL_NO, mKickStarter.get(i).getS_no());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_AMT_PLEDGED, mKickStarter.get(i).getAmt_pledged());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_BLURB, mKickStarter.get(i).getBlurb());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_BY, mKickStarter.get(i).getBy());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_COUNTRY, mKickStarter.get(i).getCountry());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_CURRENCY, mKickStarter.get(i).getCurrency());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_END_TIME, mKickStarter.get(i).getEnd_time());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_LOCATION, mKickStarter.get(i).getLocation());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_NUM_BACKERS, mKickStarter.get(i).getNum_backers());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_STATE, mKickStarter.get(i).getState());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_TITLE, mKickStarter.get(i).getTitle());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_TYPE, mKickStarter.get(i).getType());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_URL, mKickStarter.get(i).getUrl());
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_PERCENTAGE, mKickStarter.get(i).getPercentage());
            result =  db.insert(TABLE_PROJECT, null, contentValues);

        }

        if(result==-1){
            return false;
        }
        else
            return  true;


    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I am calling it in onCreate():

```
private void createDb() {
         dbHelper = new KickStarterhelper(this);
         db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         Log.e("db","db created");
    }
```

I tried to debug it, but was not able to find the issue.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating tables in sqlite database on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349337/creating-tables-in-sqlite-database-on-android)

Comment: can u print value of CREATE_PROJECT_TABLE in log and update in your question

Comment: @AmodGokhale CREATE TABLE project( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, amt_pledged TEXT, s_no TEXT, blurb TEXT, by TEXT, country TEXT, currency TEXT, end_time TEXT, location TEXT, num_backers TEXT, state TEXT, title TEXT, type TEXT, url TEXT, percentage TEXT  );

Comment: @MikeM. No I haven't surround it with try-catch, but when I run the same query in my sqlite browser its working fine.

Comment: Hunh, yeah, that doesn't seem to be a problem. Just tested. Odd. How are you determining that the table isn't created?

Comment: @MikeM. I am extracting that db and checking in the sqlite browser

Comment: @gauravtiwari your database table create successfully. please check db insert query.

Comment: @RatilalChopda I commented that db insert query and extracting the database, but I should atleast see the table structure. But the db has no table.

Comment: What is Android Os Verison?
if above or Marshmallow  then use getReadableDatabase else getWritableDatabase

Comment: @gauravtiwari please check my answer and show your created DB

Comment: The code looks fine, and as mentioned also by others works well. Do you have other SQLiteOpenHelpers in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Running your code (less the insertData method) and using

```
    KickStarterhelper kshlpr = new KickStarterhelper(this);
    CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(kshlpr.getWritableDatabase());
```

in the main activity works fine and creates a database as per :-

```
11-02 18:00:20.282 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/data/mjt.sqliteexamples/databases/cupboardTest.db
11-02 18:00:20.282 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Database Version = 3
11-02 18:00:20.282 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
11-02 18:00:20.282 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.282 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = project Created Using = CREATE TABLE project( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, amt_pledged TEXT, s_no TEXT, blurb TEXT, by TEXT, country TEXT, currency TEXT, end_time TEXT, location TEXT, num_backers TEXT, state TEXT, title TEXT, type TEXT, url TEXT, percentage TEXT  )
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = _id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = amt_pledged ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = s_no ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = blurb ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = by ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = country ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = currency ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = end_time ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = location ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = num_backers ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = state ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = title ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = type ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = url ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
11-02 18:00:20.283 4900-4900/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = project ColumnName = percentage ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
```

Considering that you say that you have increased the DB version, which should of have dropped the table and recreated it (I assume that you've also tried deleting the App's data or uninstalling the App, if not try). So I think the issue may well be with whatever method you are using to  determine that the database doesn't exist.

So you might want to try using the `logDataBaseInfo`. Below is a Class (CommonSQLiteUtilities) that contains this method and a with a few other potentially useful utilities, just create the class copy the code and start using (e.g. as above):-

```
public class CommonSQLiteUtilities {

    public static final boolean ERROR_CHECKING_ON = true;
    public static final boolean ERROR_CHECKING_OFF = false;

    // SQLite MASTER TABLE definitions
    static final String SQLITE_MASTER = "sqlite_master";
    static final String SM_TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN = "type";
    static final String SM_NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    static final String SM_TABLENAME_COLUMN = "tbl_name";
    static final String SM_ROOTPAGE_COLUMN = "rootpage";
    static final String SM_SQL_COLUMN = "sql";
    static final String SM_TYPE_TABLE = "table";
    static final String SM_TYPE_INDEX = "index";

    static final String PRAGMA_STATEMENT = "PRAGMA ";
    static final String PRAGMA_DATABASELIST = "database_list";
    static final String PRAGMA_USERVERSION = "user_version";
    static final String PRAGMA_ENCODING = "encoding";
    static final String PRAGMA_FOREIGNKEYLIST = "foreign_key_list";
    static final String PRAGMA_INDEXINFO = "index_info";
    static final String PRAGMA_INDEXLIST = "index_list";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO = "table_info";

    static final String PRAGMA_DBLIST_SEQ_COL = "seq";
    static final String PRAGMA_DBLIST_NAME_COL = "name";
    static final String PRAGMA_DBLIST_FILE_COL = "file";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_CID_COL = "cid";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_NAME_COl = "name";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_TYPE_COL = "type";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_NOTNULL_COL = "notnull";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_DEFAULTVALUE_COL = "dflt_value";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_PRIMARYKEY_COL = "pk";

    static final String CSU_TAG = "SQLITE_CSU";

    private CommonSQLiteUtilities() {}

    /**
     * Write Database information to the log;
     * Information wrttien is:
     * the database path, (will/should show connected databases)
     * the version number (note! user version i.e. version coded in DBHelper),
     * the tables in the database (includes android_metadata but not sqlite_master),
     * the columns of the tables
     * @param db    The SQLite database to be interrogated
     */
    public static void logDatabaseInfo(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // Issue PRAGMA database_list commnand
        Cursor dblcsr = db.rawQuery(PRAGMA_STATEMENT + PRAGMA_DATABASELIST,null);
        // Write databases to the log
        while (dblcsr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"DatabaseList Row " + Integer.toString(dblcsr.getPosition() + 1) +
                    " Name=" + dblcsr.getString(dblcsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_DBLIST_NAME_COL)) +
                    " File=" + dblcsr.getString(dblcsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_DBLIST_FILE_COL))
            );
        }
        dblcsr.close();
        // Issue PRAGMA user_version to get the version and write to the log
        //Note! to set user_version use execSQL not rawQuery
        Cursor uvcsr = db.rawQuery(PRAGMA_STATEMENT + PRAGMA_USERVERSION,null);
        while (uvcsr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Database Version = " +
                    Integer.toString(uvcsr.getInt(uvcsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_USERVERSION))));
        }
        uvcsr.close();
        // Select all table entry rows from sqlite_master
        Cursor tlcsr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                        SQLITE_MASTER + " WHERE " +
                        SM_TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN + "='" + SM_TYPE_TABLE + "'"
                ,null);
        // For each table write table information to the log
        // (inner loop gets column info per table)
        while (tlcsr.moveToNext()) {
            String current_table = tlcsr.getString(tlcsr.getColumnIndex(SM_TABLENAME_COLUMN));
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,
                    "Table Name = " + current_table +
                            " Created Using = " + tlcsr.getString(tlcsr.getColumnIndex(SM_SQL_COLUMN)),
                    null
            );
            // Issue PRAGMA tabel_info for the current table
            Cursor ticsr = db.rawQuery(PRAGMA_STATEMENT + PRAGMA_TABLEINFO +
                            "(" + current_table + ")",
                    null
            );
            // Write column info (see headings below) to the log
            while (ticsr.moveToNext()) {
                Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Table = " +
                                current_table +
                                " ColumnName = " +
                                ticsr.getString(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_NAME_COl)) +
                                " ColumnType = " +
                                ticsr.getString(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_TYPE_COL)) +
                                " Default Value = " +
                                ticsr.getString(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_DEFAULTVALUE_COL)) +
                                " PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = " + Integer.toString(
                        ticsr.getInt(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_PRIMARYKEY_COL))
                        )
                );
            }
            ticsr.close();
        }
        tlcsr.close();
    }

    /**
     * Generic get all rows from an SQlite table,
     * allowing the existence of the table to be checked and also
     * allowing the ROWID to be added AS a supplied string
     *
     * @param db                    The SQLiteDatabase
     * @param tablename             The name of the table from which the
     *                              returned cursor will be created from;
     *                              Note!
     * @param use_error_checking    Whether ot not to try to detect errors
     *                              currently just table doesn't exist,
     *                              true to turn on, false to turn off
     *                              ERROR_CHECKING_ON = true
     *                              ERROR_CHECKING_OFF = false
     * @param forceRowidAs          If length of string passed is 1 or greater
     *                              then a column, as an alias of ROWID, will be
     *                              added to the cursor
     * @return                      the extracted cursor, or in the case of the
     *                              underlying table not existing an empty cursor
     *                              with no columns
     */
    public static Cursor getAllRowsFromTable(SQLiteDatabase db,
                                             String tablename,
                                             boolean use_error_checking,
                                             String forceRowidAs) {
        String[] columns = null;

        // Tablename must be at least 1 character in length
        if (tablename.length() < 1) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +
                    " is finishing as the provided tablename is less than 1 character in length"
            );
            return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});
        }

        // If use_error_checking is true then check that the table exists
        // in the sqlite_master table
        if (use_error_checking) {
            Cursor chkcsr = db.query(SQLITE_MASTER,null,
                    SM_TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN + "=? AND "
                            + SM_TABLENAME_COLUMN + "=?",
                    new String[]{SM_TYPE_TABLE,tablename},
                    null,null,null
            );

            // Ooops table is not in the Database so return an empty
            // column-less cursor
            if (chkcsr.getCount() < 1) {
                Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Table " + tablename +
                        " was not located in the SQLite Database Master Table."
                );
                // return empty cursor with no columns
                return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});

            }
            chkcsr.close();
        }

        // If forcing an alias of ROWID then user ROWID AS ???, *
        if(forceRowidAs != null && forceRowidAs.length() > 0) {
            columns = new String[]{"rowid AS " +forceRowidAs,"*"};
        }

        // Finally return the Cursor but trap any exceptions
        try {
            return db.query(tablename, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Exception encountered but trapped when querying table " + tablename +
                    " Message was: \n" + e.getMessage());
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Stacktrace was:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create and return a Cursor devoid of any rows and columns
     * Not used, prehaps of very little use.
     * @param db    The Sqlite database in which the cursor is to be created
     * @return      The empty Cursor
     */
    private static Cursor getEmptyColumnLessCursor(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});
    }

    /**
     * Write column names in the passed Cursor to the log
     * @param csr   The Cursor to be inspected.
     */
    public static void logCursorColumns(Cursor csr) {
        Log.d(CSU_TAG,
                new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +
                        " invoked. Cursor has the following " +
                        Integer.toString(csr.getColumnCount())+
                        " columns.");
        int position = 0;
        for (String column: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            position++;
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Column Name " +
                    Integer.toString(position) +
                    " is "
                    + column
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write the contents of the Cursor to the log
     * @param csr   The Cursor that is to be displayed in the log
     */
    public static void logCursorData(Cursor csr) {
        int columncount = csr.getColumnCount();
        int rowcount = csr.getCount();
        int csrpos = csr.getPosition(); //<<< added 20171016
        Log.d(CSU_TAG,
                new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +
                        " Cursor has " +
                        Integer.toString(rowcount) +
                        " rows with " +
                        Integer.toString(columncount) + " columns."
        );
        csr.moveToPosition(-1);     //Ensure that all rows are retrieved <<< added 20171016
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String unobtainable = "unobtainable!";
            String logstr = "Information for row " + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition() + 1) + " offset=" + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition());
            for (int i=0; i < columncount;i++) {
                logstr = logstr + "\n\tFor Column " + csr.getColumnName(i);
                switch (csr.getType(i)) {
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is NULL";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                        logstr = logstr + "Type is FLOAT";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is INTEGER";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is STRING";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is BLOB";
                        break;
                }
                String strval_log = " value as String is ";
                String lngval_log = " value as long is ";
                String dblval_log = " value as double is ";
                String blbval_log = "";
                try {
                    strval_log = strval_log + csr.getString(i);
                    lngval_log = lngval_log + csr.getLong(i);
                    dblval_log = dblval_log +  csr.getDouble(i);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    strval_log = strval_log + unobtainable;
                    lngval_log = lngval_log + unobtainable;
                    dblval_log = dblval_log + unobtainable;
                    try {
                        blbval_log = " value as blob is " +
                                getBytedata(csr.getBlob(i),24);
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                logstr = logstr + strval_log + lngval_log + dblval_log + blbval_log;
            }
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,logstr);
        }
        csr.moveToPosition(csrpos); // restore cursor position <<< added 20171016
    }

    /**
     * Return a hex string of the given byte array
     * @param bytes     The byte array to be converted to a hexadecimal string
     * @param limit     the maximum number of bytes;
     *                  note returned string will be up to twice as long
     * @return          The byte array represented as a hexadecimal string
     */
    private static String getBytedata(byte[] bytes, int limit) {
        if (bytes.length < limit) {
            return convertBytesToHex(bytes);
        } else {
            byte[] subset = new byte[limit];
            System.arraycopy(bytes,0,subset,0,limit);
            return convertBytesToHex(subset);
        }
    }

    // HEX characters as a char array for use by convertBytesToHex
    private final static char[] hexarray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    /**
     * Return a hexadecimal string representation of the passed byte array
     * @param bytes     The byte array to be represented.
     * @return          The string representing the byte array as hexadecimal
     */
    private static String convertBytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexstr = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            int h = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
            hexstr[i * 2] = hexarray[h >>> 4];
            hexstr[i * 2 + 1] = hexarray[h & 0xF];
        }
        return new String(hexstr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added it and I am also getting the same logs but I don't why whenever I am extracting the database i can not see any table.

Comment: How are you `extracting the database`? I will try copying it via Android Device Monitor and loonging at it using SQLite Manager.

Comment: I am using this command : adb -d shell "run-as com.kickstarter.kickstarter cat /data/data/com.kickstarter.kickstarter/databases/cupboardTest.db > /sdcard/cupboardTest.db"    
adb pull /sdcard/cupboardTest.db

Comment: Works fine using Android Studio File Explorer ... Save As and then opening with SQLite Manager (browser extension). Anyway the DB and table are certainly getting created.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See this image create Database successfully

You show create DB go to android studio => Tools => Android => Android Device Monitor => then select your device packgename => after File EWxplorer => data => data => your packge =>database

Comment: db is getting created but I can not see the table.

Comment: you can export database and check sqlite manager you have display database table in sqlite manager

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

```
public static final String COLUMN_BY =  "by";
```

You can't use **`by`** as an entity name, because it is a **reserved keyword**.
For your reference: [SQLite keywords](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

From that SQLite page:

> SQLite Keywords
>
> The SQL standard specifies a huge number of keywords which may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named object. The list of keywords is so long that few people can remember them all. For most SQL code, your safest bet is to never use any English language word as the name of a user-defined object.
>
> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:
>
> 'keyword'      A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
> "keyword"      A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
> [keyword]      A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
> `keyword`        A keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and is included in SQLite for compatibility.

Comment: It's a keyword yes but it can be used as column name without problems.

Comment: @Iaalto **IF** you enclose it in escape characters, as stated in that page, you can use EVERYTHING, of course, but **not as is**.

Comment: No need for quoting. Try it yourself: `create table foo(by text); insert into foo(by) values('bar'); select by from foo order by by;` - no problems

Comment: I seriously doubt that `SELECT by FROM Foo ORDER BY by` or `SELECT Avg(by) FROM Foo GROUP BY by` can ever work... ;) Otherwise, why this statement `The SQL standard specifies a huge number of keywords which may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named object.`?